# C#/VB.Net - Enumerate Path

Tags: c#, vb.net, path, directory, enumeration

How can I get the path variable very clear in a enumeration for appdata, temp and winddir?
I tried this:

[image]

[image]

But the enumeration wont allow me to use a non-constant expression
But I still like to have the folders clean and structured listed in an enumeration, any workarrounds for this problem?

Comment: No, Emumerations must have constant value. Why not create an object with three string properties set to those variables?

Comment: Also it might be worth pointing out that Enumerations can't be a string value.

Comment: Can I also do it like this, or is that a bad coding habbit? http://puu.sh/7CNii/a7f996e8f1.png

Comment: That's how I would approach this but with a slight change. I would have them as read only properties. that way you will get closer to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to do that with an enum, but you could with a class:

```
public class MyFolder
{
    public static String Windows {get {return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");}}
    public static String AppData {get {return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appdata");}}
    public static String Temp {get {return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp");}}
}
```

I made it static so you could access like you do an enum (ie `MyFolder.Windows`).

Comment: This is a nice method, I think I will use that one =)

Answer (score 2):

Any reason not to use

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

etc?

Comment: added this in case it helps with the higher level problem